# Substring R with conditions

Tags: r

I HAVE A DATA FRAME-R

```
first <- c("robbin", "Santa", "beta", "tom" )
Last <-  c("greek", "alpha", "gamma", "angel")
Primaryphone <- c("9988776655","(123)456","(789)6543210","88")
Cellphone <- c("7896000001","1234567890","8877665","7654")
df<-data.frame(first,Last,Primaryphone,Cellphone)
```

I am trying to reproduce following output:

By taking first two letters of last name

consider only phone numbers with 10 digits , if they should not  have 10 digits it should be ignored

primary phone last 4 digits ,cellphone last 4 digits if it had 10 characters in those columns

```
Output
gr66550001
al7890
ga3210
```

Comment: Really, why are you rolling back a bunch of changes that made the question a lot easier to read?

Comment: @RonakShah, it had (789)6543210 in primary phone column has 10 chracter-and cellphone has less than 10 character so it should read only from Primaryphonecolumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  #Replace opening, closing round brackets (())
  mutate(across(c(Primaryphone, Cellphone), ~ gsub('[()]', '', .)), 
         #Change value to blank if less than 10 characters
         across(c(Primaryphone, Cellphone), ~ replace(., nchar(.) != 10, '')))  %>%
  #Keep only those rows which have 10 characters in Primaryphone or Cellphone
  filter(nchar(Primaryphone) == 10 | nchar(Cellphone) == 10) %>%
  #Paste the output using substring
  mutate(output = paste0(substring(Last, 1, 2), 
                         substring(Primaryphone, nchar(Primaryphone) - 3), 
                         substring(Cellphone, nchar(Cellphone) - 3)))

#   First  Last Primaryphone  Cellphone     output
#1 robbin greek   9988776655 7896000001 gr66550001
#2  Santa alpha              1234567890     al7890
#3   beta gamma   7896543210                ga3210
```

Comment: Thankyou it got sorted

Comment: Your solutions are always a good source of learning for me @Ronak.

Comment: @Ronak Shah , when I trying to replace code with my data it is showing output as ZH7527NA as it is adding NA if there is blank

Comment: @Ronak Shah, when I trying to replace code with my data it is showing output as ZH7527NA as it is adding NA if there is blank

Comment: @Perry You can replace `NA` with blank as well. Change in this part. `replace(., nchar(.) != 10 | is.na(.), '')`